# Clistbox the is disappeared after clicking the content in drop list

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a A class was inherited from Clistbox and B class was inherited from CGXGridWind. Then, I created the object to A in member function of B onCreat.As describe in below section:

```
int B::onCreat(LPCREATESTRUCT s)
{
    DWORD attribute = WS_CHILD| WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | LBS_NOTIFY | 
    LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL;
    BOOL bOk = m_Intellilist->Create(
    attribute,
    CRect(0, 0, 0, 0),
    this,                   //  
    IDC_L_INTELLI_LIST);
    //...TODO
}
```

It seems that everything is fine. what means for this matter is that when I type some info in one cell, the Clistbox will appear in correct, and I can select the item in drop list is analogy to picture,[image]

Nonetheless, there is a problem around the corner, This clistbox cannot appear outside this grid. the clistbox will cliped by the edge of grid when the grid have only one cell. the item just can be only displayed one or two items. Hence, I Change something that the clisbox attach to object was be changed to window of grid's parent. As see below code.

```
int B::onCreat(LPCREATESTRUCT s)
{
    DWORD attribute = WS_CHILD| WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | LBS_NOTIFY | 
    LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL;
    BOOL bOk = m_Intellilist->Create(
    attribute,
    CRect(0, 0, 0, 0),
    this->GetParent(),  // Or this->GetSafeOwner()   
    IDC_L_INTELLI_LIST);
    //...TODO
}
```

There is a problem coming with this change, I cannot click item and select it, this clistbox will be disappeared in this case.

did someone can provide assistance for me?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I can use the scroll,but the item cannot be clicked,and it will be disappeared after clicking.

Comment: It's not clear what is `onCreat` (do you mean `OnCreate`?)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks you for your anwser, Man! This question have been resolved by myself. Hence, It should be got the status of close.

Comment: A question on Stack Overflow gets closed either, because it was deemed not useful by the community, or by way of accepting a proposed answer. If you solved the issue yourself, post an answer and accept it. Make sure to take the [tour] to learn, how Stack Overflow works.